# How to get a rounded corners color clip using MoviePy?

Tags: python, moviepy

I'm working on a small video project using Python and MoviePy, and I want to create a color clip with rounded corners to use as a background. However, I'm unsure how to achieve this effect. So far I have a rectangle background !!. Can anyone give me a small example on how to add rounded corners to a color clip in MoviePy?

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, TextClip, CompositeVideoClip, ColorClip
# Create a color clip as the background
color_clip = ColorClip(size=(video_clip.size[0], video_clip.size[1]),
                       color=(0, 0, 0), duration=video_clip.duration)

# Set the opacity of the color clip
color_clip = color_clip.set_opacity(0.4)

# Set the position of the color clip and text clip
color_clip = color_clip.set_position('center')
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a bubble like this:

```py
from moviepy.editor import *

bubble_size = 30  # diameter of the bubble

# 1. Create a square ColorClip for the bubble
bubble = ColorClip(size=(bubble_size, bubble_size), color=(255, 255, 255))

# 2. Create a mask that is black everywhere except for a white circle in the center
def make_circle_mask(size):
    Y, X = np.ogrid[:size, :size]
    center = size / 2
    distance_from_center = np.sqrt((X - center)**2 + (Y - center)**2)
    mask = 255 * (distance_from_center <= size / 2)
    return mask.astype(np.uint8)

circle_mask = ImageClip(make_circle_mask(bubble_size), ismask=True)

# 3. Apply the mask to the ColorClip to get a round bubble
bubble = bubble.set_mask(circle_mask)
```

**Now you can position and overlay the bubble on your video as needed.**

---

***Alternative Easier Solution:***
If you have an image of a bubble (or any other shape) that you'd like to use, you can simply load it with ImageClip and overlay it on your video. This might be easier if you want a more complex or stylized bubble shape. However, if you're looking for a simple round white bubble, the method above should work just fine.